# Hosting a wordpress blog parallel with a django app

Tags: django, wordpress, apache

I would like to host a blog at a subfolder of my domain, which is covered by a django app. I'm most of the way there, but I need some help getting over the finish line, as it were.

Currently, if I go to `domain.com`, the django app is served correctly. If I go to `domain.com/blog/`, the blog is served correctly. However, if I go to `domain.com/blog` (note the missing trailing slash), the urlconf returns a URL not found error.

I've tried a couple of things, including:

- Reordering the `Alias`, `Directory`, and `WSGIScriptAlias` statements in my Apache configuration
- Having the django urlconf trap the `domain.com/blog` condition and redirect to `domain.com/blog/` (probably unsurprisingly causing an infinite loop of redirects)

What are my next steps?

Here is the relevant part of my Apache conf:

```
Alias /blog/ /var/www/blog/

<Directory /var/www/blog/>
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Chris, removing the trailing slash from the Alias statement did it. Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Apache in years, but try aliasing just /blog instead of /blog/. The problem currently is that Apache is not catching it, so it's being passed to Django. If that doesn't work, you might also try setting up a 301 redirect in your Apache conf to redirect to the slash version, thereby avoiding Django altogether.